Why can't a macro of a package redefined in init file be loaded?
I've made sure the macro re-definition is specified inside with-eval-after-load macro.
To be specific, I'm trying to alter a macro of the package denote.el, and writing a re-definition in the init file, however, the macro is not redefined, but still being the original one.
Here's the original macro:
(defmacro denote--with-conditional-completion (fn prompt history &optional initial-value default-value)
  "Produce body of FN that may perform completion.
Use PROMPT, HISTORY, INITIAL-VALUE, and DEFAULT-VALUE as arguments for
the given minibuffer prompt."
  `(if (denote--prompt-with-completion-p ,fn)
       ;; NOTE 2023-10-27: By default SPC performs completion in the
       ;; minibuffer.  We do not want that, as the user should be able to
       ;; input an arbitrary string, while still performing completion
       ;; against their input history.
       (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
           (lambda ()
             (use-local-map
              (let ((map (make-composed-keymap nil (current-local-map))))
                (define-key map (kbd "SPC") nil)
                map)))
         (completing-read ,prompt ,history nil nil ,initial-value ',history ,default-value))
     (read-string ,prompt ,initial-value ',history ,default-value)))

The re-definition in the init file:
(with-eval-after-load 'denote
  (with-eval-after-load 'denote-silo-extras
    (defun my-deploy/denote-prompt-indicator ()
      "Return the last name of the path in the `denote-directory’ variable.
If the path is a silo path, return ’Silo:_LastName_’, else return ’Dir:_LastName_’."
      (if-let ((req-var 'denote-directory)
           (cur-dir (or (symbol-value req-var))))
      (let* ((silo-dirs (or denote-silo-extras-directories))
         (indicator (if (member cur-dir silo-dirs)
                (concat "Silo: " cur-dir)
                  (concat "Dir: " cur-dir))))
        indicator
        )
    (user-error "The required variable ’%s’ is non-existent or nil." req-var))))
  
  (defmacro denote--with-conditional-completion (fn prompt history &optional initial-value default-value)
    "Produce body of FN that may perform completion.
Use PROMPT, HISTORY, INITIAL-VALUE, and DEFAULT-VALUE as arguments for
the given minibuffer prompt."
    `(if (denote--prompt-with-completion-p ,fn)
     (let ((prompt-local (concat (my-deploy/denote-prompt-indicator) ,prompt)))
       ;; NOTE 2023-10-27: By default SPC performs completion in the
       ;; minibuffer.  We do not want that, as the user should be able to
       ;; input an arbitrary string, while still performing completion
       ;; against their input history.
       (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
           (lambda ()
         (use-local-map
          (let ((map (make-composed-keymap nil (current-local-map))))
            (define-key map (kbd "SPC") nil)
            map)))
         (completing-read prompt-local ,history nil nil ,initial-value ',history ,default-value)))
       (read-string ,prompt ,initial-value ',history ,default-value))))
(require 'denote)
(require 'denote-silo-extras)


Perhaps because denote.el has all macros expanded when it is compiled to an elc file.

Unquestionably so.  It's the macro definitions which were defined at compile time that are relevant.  The byte-compiled code contains no macro calls at all.

Is there a workaround for this?

Do not compile it.  Or put your code into denote.el.

It's a bit dirty this way, but it works fine as long as the package stays not updated.
